# How to export a model with textures from blender to unity

Tags: export, unity

[image: enter code here]

I'm trying to export an mmd model that I have on Blender to Unity .

But it shows without textures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Please use the search function. It's there for a reason and this question gets asked numerous times per week.